# Where is module being imported from?

Tags: python

Assuming I have two Python modules and path_b is in the import path:

```
# file: path_b/my_module.py
print "I was imported from ???"

#file: path_a/app.py
import my_module
```

Is it possible to see where the module is imported from? I want an output like "I was imported from path_a/app.py", if I start app.py (because I need the file name).

**Edit:**
For better understanding; I could write:

```
# file: path_b/my_module.py
def foo(file):
    print "I was imported from %s" % file

#file: path_a/app.py
import my_module
my_module.foo(__file__)
```

So the output would be:

```
$> python path_app.py
I was imported from path_a/app.py
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There may be an easier way to do this, but this works:

```
import inspect

print(inspect.getframeinfo(inspect.getouterframes(inspect.currentframe())[1][0])[0])
```

Note that the path will be printed relative to the current working directory if it's a parent directory of the script location.

Comment: … and that easier way is: `inspect.stack(0)[1][1]`. Note however than in Python 3 you'll see a bunch of `importlib` related things in trace, so you'll likely have to iterate over `inspect.stack(0)` instead to find what you're looking for.

Comment: AttributeError: 'FrameInfo' object has no attribute 'f_lineno'

Answer (score 115):

Try this:

```
>>> import my_module
>>> my_module.__file__
'/Users/myUser/.virtualenvs/foobar/lib/python2.7/site-packages/my_module/__init__.pyc'
```

*Edit*

In that case write into the `__init__.py` file of your module:

```
print("%s: I was imported from %s" %(__name__, __file__))
```

Comment: After the calling 'app.py' I want the path from 'app.py' inside the 'my_module' module.

Comment: This doesn't work for `from module import thing`; then `thing.__file__` will not be present.

Answer (score 16):

Try `my_module.__file__` to find out where it is from. If you get an `AttributeError`, it is probably not a Python source (.py) file.

Answer (score 14):

Also, if you have a function/class `f` from a module `m` you can get the path of the module using the module `inspect`

```
import inspect
from m import f

print inspect.getmodule(f)
```

Comment: That is significantly more useful than the accepted answer!

Answer (score 12):

This is how I do it:

```
print(module_name.__path__)
```

Answer (score 8):

I've written a simple script so I have the command `pywhich`
that allows me to find where a Python module comes from.
It doesn't work for some builtins like sys which doesn't have a `\__file__` attribute.

This can be run from a Linux command line to find where a python script run in the current environment will get a module from, for example:

`% pywhich os`

---

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
def pywhich(module_name):
    module = __import__(module_name, globals(), locals(), [], 0)
    return module.__file__

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    print(pywhich(sys.argv[1]))
```

Comment: please post an example output

Comment: Works for me with Python2.7.I get an ValueError with python3 "ValueError: level must be >= 0"

Comment: According to the Python online manual: 
Changed in version 3.3: Negative values for level are no longer supported (which also changes the default value to 0).
So change the -1 to 0 in the call to \_\_import\_\_

Comment: Using 0 works in 2.7 so I've changed it in the given example

Comment: 'xactly what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to see where a module is stored, for example `setuptools`, type in shell:

`$ python -c "import setuptools; print(setuptools.__file__)"`

Comment: How would you get the path and name of the `*.dll` related to the module? (If on windows.)

Comment: I get the error `ValueError: level must be >= 0` when running this on Windows 10 with Python 3.7.

Comment: Did not work for Seaborn; the __path__ solution below by Burkhow did.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know where file `x.py` is being imported from - you could add `raise RuntimeError()` to the first line of `x.py` and inspect the stacktrace...

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any additional packages. For `python3`:

```
python3 -m pip show <focal_package>
```

Answer (score -5):

Other answers are OK, but if you want to tell it from *inside* the imported module then do

```
print "I was imported from %s" % __file__
```