# Is there a way to get the name of the 'parent' module from an imported module?

Tags: python

I'm curious if it's possible to access the name of the parent module that some other module is imported into.

For instance, if I have a module (`moduleA`) and a parent is module, `foo.py`, into which it will be imported into, is it possible for `moduleA` to know where `foo` is located ?

#### ModuleA

```
def print_parent_module(): 
    os.path.asbpath(#somehow access filename of parent module)
```

#### foo.py

```
import moduleA 

print moduleA.print_parent_module()
>>> "foo.py"
```

Comment: A module can be imported into many other modules, so there is no such thing as "the" module that imports it.

Comment: I think he means to ask whether you can write a function that recognizes the file name that is importing it (from an external module)

Comment: @yuvi Yeah! I explained it poorly, but that's what I'm asking.

Comment: Possible, yes. A good idea? Certainly not. If you're asking with the intent to actually do it, don't.

Comment: @ZackYoshyaro try using the builtin [`__file__`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632199/how-do-i-get-the-path-of-the-current-executed-file-in-python) magic method to get the name of the current file. As in, `os.path.abspath(__file__)`.

Comment: @Droogans Tired that one. Unfortunately it gives the path to the module in which it is written, not the module it's imported into.

Comment: @delnan I learn best from mistakes ;) Care to explain how it is done (even though you don't recommend it?)

Comment: I can't be bothered to look up the details necessary for a full answer, but basically you inspect the call stack (at module level, not inside `print_parent_module`).

Comment: The more general question you're asking already has an answer, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7150998/where-is-module-being-imported-from and related answers. You need to use inspect lib.

Answer (score 7):

I ran into a similar issue. You could make use of `__name__`:

```
parent_name = '.'.join(__name__.split('.')[:-1])
```

Or if you try to access the module directly (not the OP's question but related), see my answer in [Is there a way to access parent modules in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5286210/is-there-a-way-to-access-parent-modules-in-python/45895490)

Comment: I needed this answer. I was trying to make a root logger for my application in one module in a directory, and have all loggers in that directory propagate up to it. It wasn't working because its module name was too specific, thus I needed the parent directory of the module.

Comment: Use rsplit for (slightly) faster code and certainly more readable. I wouldn't count on it being faster in a benchmark though, who knows

Comment: slightly shorter ways: `parent_name = __name__.rsplit('.', 1)[0]`, and `parent_name = __name__.rpartition('.')[0]`

Answer (score 1):

No. Imported modules do not hold any form of state which stores data related to how they are imported.

I think the better question is, why would you even want to do it this way? You're aware that if `foo.py` is indeed your `__main__` then you can easily get the name `foo.py` out of it (by using sys.argv)? And if `foo.py` is an imported module instead, then you obviously already know the name of `foo.py` and its location, etc. at the time that you import it.

Comment: It seems a little convoluted, I'm sure, but the reason for wanting to do it this way is for decorating a main func in a way that the client code doesn't need to pass any args to the decorator. I figured out a simple work around (posted it as an answer below).

Answer (score 0):

Here is something I came with to store a parent's method name and variables to be recalled later in the class with a decorator.

```
import inspect
from functools import wraps

def set_reuse_vars(method):
    @wraps(method)
    def _impl(self, *method_args, **method_kwargs):
        func_current = inspect.currentframe()
        self.recall_func = dict()
        self.recall_func['method_kwargs'] = func_current.f_locals['method_kwargs']
        self.recall_func['method_name'] = func_current.f_locals['method'].__name__
        return method(self, *method_args, **method_kwargs)
    return _impl

class APIData(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.client = None
        self.response = None
        self.recall_func = None

    def get_next_page(self):
        # Takes a pageToken to return the next result
        get_func = getattr(self, self.recall_func['method_name'])
        self.recall_func['method_kwargs']['pageToken'] = self.response['nextPageToken']
        return get_func(**self.recall_func['method_kwargs'])

    @set_reuse_vars
    def search_list_by_keyword(self, **kwargs):

        self.response = self.client.search().list(
            **kwargs
        ).execute()

        return self.response
```

script to run it.

```
api_data = APIData()


results = api_data.search_list_by_keyword(
                       part='snippet',
                       maxResults=25,
                       order='date')


print(results)

resultsTwo = api_data.get_next_page()

print(resultsTwo)
```

Answer (score -2):

Figured it out!

A little import statement inside of the function can give access to the module name.

#### moduleA

```
def print_module_name():
    import sys
    return sys.argv[0]
```

Then, inside the "parent" module

```
# foo.py
import os 
import moduleA

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print os.path.split(moduleA.print_module_name())[-1]
```

Gives:

```
>>> 'foo.py'
```

Comment: This is just printing the name of the script you're running. It has nothing to do with imports.

Comment: @IsmailBadawi Well.. That was what my question was. How to get the parent module that another module was imported into. This does that. I'm thinking I just explained what I was trying to accomplish very poorly.. :/

Comment: But that's not what this is doing. This is printing the name of the script you're running. If you run foo.py, and it imports A, and A imports B, then `B.print_module_name()` will return foo.py, not A.

Comment: Conceivably this is the solution to your problem. However, it's not the answer to the question you asked.

Comment: @IsmailBadawi, Ohhh... I see what you're saying now.  My apologies. Yeah, I explained my question quite poorly it seems! By "module name," I guess I meant "name of the script that's calling the imported function."

Comment: @DavidHeffernan yeah, that seems to be the concensus. I'll edit or delete when I get back to a proper computer.