# Does Django execute all the python files in its project directory?

Tags: python, django

I'm not sure what the best way of phrasing this question, but I am noticing that if I have say this file in the project directory:

**a.py**

```
import logging
import track

from raven.contrib.django.raven_compat.models import client
from django.conf import settings

from .MetricLogger import log_metrics


_LOG = logging.getLogger('application')


class TrackingClass(track.SubClass):
    def record(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            metrics = {
                "metric": 'something',
                "trigger": 'request',
                "element": 'request'
            }

            # log_metrics(None, metrics)
        except Exception:
            client.captureException()

track.tracker.register(EventsappTrackingPixel) # this line gets called at some point without importing this module
```

The print statement gets called. What is happening and what is triggering it? Is this part of the class indexing that needs to be done or how is this working?

**EDIT:
Turns out the track package we depend on is specifically looking for this filename in the root directory and importing it!**

Comment: The print gets called when you do what?

Comment: @wim, I'm honestly confused on when it gets called. I'm basing this example that is in our codebase... instead of print it's another library call to this pixel tracker that is supposed to register the class within the file. I'm updating the example in my question to be clearer and more similar to what we actually have

Comment: @wim I was told that this file gets imported how admin.py is imported. I'm not sure what that means.

Comment: What's the real filename, presumably not `a.py`.  grep your code for the import statements.  Django does not just randomly import modules lying around in the project directory!

Comment: @wim... that's what I thought... there is no use of it in the entire repo... I wonder if some other internal app we depend on looks for this kind of file in the directory

Comment: @Jaime: just inspect the stack via `traceback.print_stack()` and post it in your question. That will reveal the answer

Comment: I am actually not seeing this file get called... but I figured out that the dependency that we have is looking for this file with this specific name! doh!

Comment: That's possible.  Celery does this for example, looking for modules called `tasks.py`.  The suggestion from @AndreaCorbellini is a good one to investigate.

Comment: wim is correct. Django never imports arbitrarily named modules just because they are sitting in a project or app directory. Files in an app directory named "admin.py" can an exception because of `admin.autodiscover()`, and files named "models.py" can be an exception because of ORM. Also, the module named by ROOT_URLCONF is imported at server start, which imports app.urls, which import views, which import models and forms, and so on. If you can't trace it manually, there is an introspection trick you might try: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7150998/where-is-module-being-imported-from

Answer (score 0):

Django does not automatically import all files within a directory. It only automatically imports specific predefined files (should they exist), such as models.py and apps.py.

If you have additional custom modules in the directory, like profanityDetector.py, you'll need to manually import them, perhaps within apps.py.

Note that in Django, all modules are imported only once per worker process. This means that if you are not manually importing `a.py` from another module, it must have been registered as a callback through Django's logging system, possibly due to a pathing or directory mixup.

Answer (score -1):

The call to `print` is not part of the class definition. It's at the module level, therefore it gets executed when the module is imported.

You can figure out what is triggering the import by inspecting the call stack. Insert these two lines right after (or before) the call to `print`:

```
import traceback
traceback.print_stack()
```

Comment: Django doesn't (or shouldn't) import the module, though.

Comment: @wim: why not? If the module is, for example, the `models.py` of an app, then it will be imported at startup. The same can happen indirectly, e.g. if the module is gets imported from another module

Comment: Right, but OP just said it's `a.py` in the project directory.  Still awaiting clarification on what action triggers that print.