# Getting script filepath from an imported python module

Tags: python-3.x

Let say I have a file `a/b/c.py` with following content.

```py
import mymodule
a = mymodule.MyClass()
print(a.scriptpath)
```

I want `a.scriptpath` to print `a/b/c.py`. Essentially, what I am asking: Is there a way for `MyClass.__init__` or `mymodule.__init__.py` to know from which file they are being called?

Answer (score 2):

Why not just instantiate the class with that information:

```
a = mymodule.MyClass(__file__)
```

Comment: Is it possible to do it without asking the user? `inspect` module looks promising.

Comment: Yes. In that case, there are answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7150998/where-is-module-being-imported-from

Comment: I ended up using `inspect` module. Thanks @costaparas .